# launch intent in errorListener

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to launch an intent in an onErrorListener. By default if the video fails to launch, the MediaPlayer stops, displays a popup "The video couldn't be played" and goes back to the main activity. What I'd like to do is, in the ideal, in the MediaPlayer.ErrorListener, displaying my own popup, putting a positiveButton, and when the positiveButton is clicked to launch a new intent by myself which brings me back to the main activity.

The reason is that it would be easier to deal with connection errors or no. In fact I try to connect RTSP streams and if I can detect why the user cannot reach the ipcam I needn't use a RTSP client to deal with the connection states, etc.

Anyway this does not seem possible, because you cannot launch another intent in a method which returns something. and the method onError needs a boolean return, so I cannot even launch a new intent properly ([and neither display a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added))

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(PlayVideo.this, IPCamInformationsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("error", "true");
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: There is nothing that should prevent you from calling `startActivity()` in this case. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Well that's strange. Anyway I'm making another project. This one needs code improvements

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
@Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        try{
        return true;
        }
        finally{
         Intent intent = new Intent(PlayVideo.this, IPCamInformationsActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("error", "true");
         startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: lol that's a nice trick. I've just tried it but it doesn't work. Anyway I'm not sure it's the fault of this code, it seems I have an error before entering here. I'm gonna edit my post to set the error, apparently when the mediaplayer crashes it doesn't not enter anymore into the errorListener. There is a nullPointerException exactly on the line videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener()

Comment: In fact this error is related to the MediaPlayer. I launch the Activity alone with a custom url and as it doesn't find it the app exits. I think it is the same when I launch it with the other activity, it closes the MediaPlayer activity to go back on the first one. So I get the error given in the link.